# "noone", "no one" or "no-one"?

Tags: orthography

What is the correct form? Does context play a role?

Are there noticeable trends towards the awkward "noone" or is it just a by-product of careless orthography on the Internet?

Comment: No-one cares. Haha, sorry, I just had to. I obviously care since I came here looking for the answer. There are conflicting answers on several grammar sites though. Maybe I should call Sister Dorothy, my sixth grade english teacher :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

"[no one](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20one)" is the correct one.

[noone](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noone) is the common misspelling of "no one".

> "Noone" is formed for consistency with
>   "nobody", and also its opposites
>   "anyone" and "everyone", but it is
>   still considered nonstandard because
>   of the doubled vowels creating a
>   temptation to read and pronounce it as
>   "noon" (/nuːn/).

On the other hand, [no-one](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no-one) is the alternative spelling of "no one". I don't think it's widely used.

Comment: Correction: `no-one` is quite widely used within British English. `noone` is indeed wrong.

Comment: I agree with @Noldorin. Though "no-one"is not particularly good-looking either, I don't use "no one", because it feels very much like one word, and because of slight confusion in sentences like "no one word could express this" (though perhaps you would use "single" in this example). Besides, I think "nobody" often replaces it at any rate.

Comment: @Noldorin: Mostly in my experience, the British use `no one`.  Though I have seen all three aplenty.

Comment: @Orbling: I see both quite a lot to be honest. Don't ask for statistics though. :)

Comment: And yeah. Personally, I prefer `no-one` since it suggests that it's one (compound word), as it really is.

Comment: I find myself often mistaking `noone` for `noon` and not `no one`. That said, yeah it's not a word anyway.

Comment: No love for noöne?

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Wow, I didn't know about [noöne](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no%C3%B6ne).

Comment: @Mehper: Yeah, I wasn't joking.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Haha, I love it. There should be more diaereses in English!

Comment: @JonPurdy [There is now.](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/195335)

Comment: I thought [Noone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Noone) was a Hermit.

Comment: I am British and I typically use no-one and 'no one' interchangeably.

Answer (score -4):

I have seen all three types used. I use either noone or no one and they are all accepted. I never use no-one because it just doesn't flow right for me.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and your answer could be improved with references or examples that demonstrate the acceptance beyond personal anecdote. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for a better understanding of our format and conventions.

Comment: The usage of 'noone' in literature does not support this claim. 'No one' is definitely the correct usage: http://i.imgur.com/gobhv18.jpg